# Android load image bad quality

Tags: android, image

My code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
fonImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fon2 , options);
```

In the emulator, it looks like. On a real device the same

[image]

P.S. real image with beautiful blur

UPD if its important I use fon2.jpg image;

UPD2 I try this code

```
Log.e("" , fonImg.getConfig().toString());
E/﹕ ARGB_8888
```

Comment: `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` stores each pixels on 4 bytes. Use something else and compare.

Comment: I try use defaule(BitmapFactory.decodeResource without options) ,but the result was the same-

Comment: The image might have got transformed in a way. How do you provide it to your application? res/drawable? assets? network download?

Comment: oh , I just start learn java...

I add image in app/src/main/res/drawable/{somethingDPI} , and next fonImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fon2 , options);